# Installing Samsung Gear Companion app (with /assets/app.wgt) never installs on the watch

Tags: android, tizen

I am trying to install a Samsung Gear Companion app (an APK file packaged with a WGT file), but the Gear Manager never installs the WGT part on the watch. I have installed all certificates etc., the .wgt file is correctly placed in the /assets/ folder.

I can install the WGT using Tizen SDK and it is working fine and communicating with the host app on the phone. What could be causing this? There are no errors, it just silently does not install.

Comment: If possible can u share the apk?

Comment: Are you trying on a Samsung Gear S2?